# Reading only the integers from a txt file and adding the value up for each found

Tags: java

I am trying to read a txt file that contains strings with integers. I would like to be able to get just the integers from this file and add the value each to create a total. I have managed to read the file fine and have been able to identify the ints and non. How would I go about adding the integers together?

```java
public void goalCount() throws FileNotFoundException {

  int goals=0;
  double total=0;

  try {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("validtest.txt.txt"));

    // find the next int token and print it
    // loop for the whole scanner
    while (scan.hasNext()) {  

      // if the next is a int, print found and the int
      if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Found :" + scan.nextInt());
        //goals = scan.nextInt();
        //total+= goals;
      }
      // if no int is found, print "Not Found:" and the token
      System.out.println("Not Found :" + scan.next());
    }

    // close the scanner
    scan.close();

  } catch(Exception e) {

  }
  System.out.println("Total Goals:"+total); //error handling
}
```

#### Example of the txt file

```
Leeds United : Liverpool : 1 : 2
Chelsea :  Manchester City : 1 : 1
Aston Villa : Middlesbrough : 3 : 1
Tottenham Hotspur : Stoke City : 0 : 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**
You'll have to excuse me, that method will not work.  What you need to do is read one line at a time, then split the line by each space, to get an array of words.  From there you can identify integers and store the value.

```
final static String filename = "FILENAME.txt";

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner scan = null;
      File f = new File(filename);
      try {
         scan = new Scanner(f);
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.out.println("File not found.");
         System.exit(0);
      }

      int total = 0;
      boolean foundInts = false; //flag to see if there are any integers

      while (scan.hasNextLine()) { //Note change
         String currentLine = scan.nextLine();
         //split into words
         String words[] = currentLine.split(" ");

         //For each word in the line
         for(String str : words) {
            try {
               int num = Integer.parseInt(str);
               total += num;
               foundInts = true;
               System.out.println("Found: " + num);
            }catch(NumberFormatException nfe) { }; //word is not an integer, do nothing
         }
      } //end while 

      if(!foundInts)
         System.out.println("No numbers found.");
      else
         System.out.println("Total: " + total);

      // close the scanner
      scan.close();
   }
```

Comment: I have tried to implement this in put it doesnt seem to run the while statement at all. System.out.println("Found :" + foundInteger); doesnt seem to be triggered.

Comment: I have updated the code. My apologies, I should have compiled it before answering you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing out the integer, you can add them to a list.

```
List<Integer> goals = new ArrayList<Integer>();
goals.add(scan.nextInt());
```

And then add them up!

Or if you don't need access to them individually, you can simply,

```
total = total + scan.nextInt(); //OR total += scan.nextInt();
```

In your `if(scan.hasNextInt())` block

Comment: That worked perfect thanks for the help wasnt sure which direction to head in.

Comment: Great! If it worked for you... then it's good practice to accept the answer so that it can help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your file name looks incorrect change it to :-

```
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("validtest.txt"));
```

Then i believe you already have logic just uncomment that adding part in your code.

```
  if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                System.out.println("Found :" + scan.nextInt());
                goals = scan.nextInt();
                total+= goals;
             }
```

Comment: Change it to ... what? You haven't changed anything.

Comment: corrected it, i believe your filename is validtest.txt.

Comment: Sorry Zach's , I didn't checked that someone else has asked question. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Zach is the OP and I'm not him :D. But this is not important.

Answer (score 0):

You have done all the work and stuck with simple addition. Declare a variable `total` and add integers(values) to it. In the code block, `if(scan.hasNextInt())` add the following statement :
`total += scan.nextInt()`.

*Do not forget to declare the variable before hand.*

Answer (score 0):

your code doesn't really do what your comments claim it does maybe you want this?

```
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public void goalCount(){
                int goals=0;// i dont see where this is used
                double total=0;
             try{
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("validtest.txt.txt"));
                while (scan.hasNext()) {
                    String temp=scan.next();
                     if (isInteger(temp)) {
                         total+=Integer.ParseInt(temp);
                        System.out.println("Found :" + temp);
                     }
                     else{
                    System.out.println("Not Found :" + temp);}
                  }
                  scan.close();
               }
            catch(Exception e){

            }
               System.out.println("Total Goals:"+total); 
            }

    }
    public boolean isInteger( String input ) {
        Pattern p=Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
        return input.matches(p.pattern());}
    }
    }
```